# When closing > off-topic add padding / spacing to make text more clear

Tags: feature-request, design, close-dialog

When I mark a question to be closed / off topic I am presented with some reasons.  Can we add some padding between each line so that the text doesnt appear so close to each other.  For instance, look at how close the S in stack overflow basically touches the word asking below:

[image]

Place some padding between each line to make it more clear..it really appears very jumbled right now.

Comment: This has already been fixed in the redesign that is to be pushed to Stack Overflow. You can check it out on MSO. I think the spacing looks much better there.

Comment: I posted this because the issue was on SO but I didn't check MSO so thank you if its fixed.